# Dynamically cast 'obj' to function type indicated by reflection

Tags: f#

I'm pattern matching F# quotations, and want to call a function referenced inside the quotation. The simplified code looks like this:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.Patterns
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.DerivedPatterns

let ModelValidator (validator : 'T -> bool) (valueToValidate : 'T) : 'T = 
    failwith "Don't call me!"

let foo expr =
    match expr with
    | SpecificCall <@ ModelValidator @> (None, genericTypeInstantiation::[], 
                                        [ Value(validator, validatorType); source ]) ->
        let value = getValue source // Will return an 'obj'
        // Now, I want to call 'validator value', but how?
        // This will obviously not work, but it shows in principle what I want to do:
        let castedValue : genericTypeInstantiation = unbox value
        let castedFunction : genericTypeInstantiation -> bool = unbox validator
        castedFunction castedValue
    | _ -> failwith "..."


let myIntValidator (x : int) =
    x = 42

let myStringValidator (x : string) =
    x = "foo"

let a = foo <@ ModelValidator myIntValidator 44 @>
let b = foo <@ ModelValidator myStringValidator "bar" @>
```

The dummy function `ModelValidator` is generic and acts as a sort of placeholder or tag, i.e. something to put in a match case in the pattern match. It also helps enforce type safety in the quotations.

In the match case for the call to `ModelValidator`, I want to call `validator value`, but both `validator` and `value` are of type `obj` and their types are only known during runtime, so how can I do this?

Note that `genericTypeInstantiation` is a `System.Type` which holds the type of the `validator` argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do it with a little bit of Reflection magic

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.Patterns
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.DerivedPatterns

let ModelValidator (validator : 'T -> bool) (valueToValidate : 'T) : 'T = 
    failwith "Don't call me!"

type Invoker private () =
    static let CallMethodInfo = 
        let flags = System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic ||| System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static
        typeof<Invoker>.GetMethod("DoCall", flags).GetGenericMethodDefinition()

    static member private DoCall<'T>(validator: obj, value: obj): bool =
        let validator: 'T -> bool = unbox validator
        let value: 'T = unbox value
        validator value

    static member Call(validator: obj, value: obj, typeOfValue: System.Type): bool =
        CallMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(typeOfValue).Invoke(null, [|validator; value|]) :?> _

let foo expr =
    match expr with
    | SpecificCall <@ ModelValidator @> (None, [genericTypeInstantiation], [ Value(validator, validatorType); source ]) ->
        let value = getValue source // Will return an 'obj'
        Invoker.Call(validator, value, genericTypeInstantiation)
    | _ -> failwith "..."
```